How do I solve Nashorn removal and JS replacement in Netbeans 22?
Despite having followed every procedure exactly as specified to install an alternative to Nashorn in Netbeans 22, I still get the following error when trying to build a FXML project:
Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself.
GraalVM JavaScript is the js that I am trying to integrate. Following the Oracle graalvm page I downloaded and extracted the following:
https://download.oracle.com/graalvm/22/latest/graalvm-jdk-22_windows-x64_bin.zip
Extracted the download to the directory C:Program Files/Java/graalvm-jdk-22.0.1+8.1
and renamed the folder graalvm-22
In an admin cmd shell, set JAVA_HOME environment variable with:
setx /M JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\graalvm-22"

and set the path with:
setx /M PATH "C:\Progra~1\Java\<graalvm>\bin;%PATH%"

Checked these variables with echo, which showed:
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Progra~1\Java\graalvm-22

echo %PATH%
C:\Progra~1\Java\graalvm-22\bin;
C:\Program Files\CommonFiles\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\HP\HP One Agent;C:\Users\qabpa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

I have been stuck for a few days with this issue and would appreciate help. Thanks.

"https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core/15.4" find jar dowload link "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjdk/nashorn/nashorn-core/15.4/nashorn-core-15.4.jar"

OK, so mvnrepository points to OpenJDK Nashorn » 15.4 followed by 5 lines of xml code. Does one have to do something with this code, and if so, what does one have to do?

find files jar (2.1 MB), click the link, download the jar file. Put the jar file info your app dirctory( EX:  C:\myapp). add the jar file full path to your CLASSPATH.

Is CLASSPATH the same as PATH or does a completely new variable CLASSPATH have to be created, for example: setx /M CLASSPATH "C:\MyApp\nashorn-core-15.4"

"exactly as specified" — specified where? Link to the instructions you followed.

Do you use a build system, e.g. Maven or Gradle?

@life88888 Same error after setting CLASSPATH: -jfx-copylibs: Java 15 has removed Nashorn...Unable to create javax script engine for javascript

@jabaa No I was trying to avoid both of these, they seem excessive for what I want to do which is develop small desktop applications with JavaFXML. Everything functioned perfectly in Netbeans 12 but it appears impossible to update and develop legacy apps in NB22

Maven and Gradle are build systems and dependency managers. If I correctly understand, you want to manage a dependency (it was discussed in the comments). With these systems, you only have to copy and paste the XML snippet. I recommend one of these systems. "Despite having followed every procedure exactly as specified" Can you post a link to the specification?

It was the specification described in https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/jdk/22/docs/getting-started/installation-windows/. Re the snippet you mention, where does one copy it from and where/what is it pasted into?

In NetBeans when you go to the menu item "Tools" > "Java Platforms", what do you see? Do you need to add your GraalVM platform ("Add platform") and then select it in NetBeans?

I see JDK 22 (default).  On click "Add platform" I see three radio buttons "Java SE", "Remote Java SE" and "Download OpenJDK". Which one do I select?

@Rusty - Are you restricted and must use graalvm? Are other JDKs acceptable?

Click on  "Java Standard Edition" and then navigate to the folder where Graal is installed - and select it.

In your Java project in NetBeans, you also have to tell the project that you want to use this specific Java platform: Make sure you are in the project already, and then go to File > Project Properties > Build > Compile > Java platform. Select the Graal platform.

After this, you will want to look into Graal Truffle, by the way. This is not Nashorn - it is an alternative to Nashorn, also with a "compatibility mode". More guidance here.

@life888888 Not restricted to graal or anything else, just totally and utterly confused. Just want to get up and running.

So far I have tried Zulu-22.30.13, Openjfx-22-0-1 with mods, Openjfx-22-0-1 bin, graalvm-jdk-22 win64 and nashorn-core-15.4 without success. Is there anything remaining to try out? If there simply is no solution, I would rather know and then try and move on with something else.

@andrew.james "Click on "Java Standard Edition" and then navigate to the folder where Graal is installed" has no effect and the compiler message "Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself. GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option." is still there.

Right - hence my "this is not Nashorn" comment. I guess you don't want GraalVM in your specific case, as noted  by @life888888 in their excellent answer. I hope that approach solves your issues.

@life888888 Thanks for a brilliant tutorial, I have got as far as Create Script Engine and as this is new territory I want to study it carefully. Up to now everything works. One missing step I found was Config JavaFX where I found the plugin from "Available Plugins" and then the procedure followed your sequence as described. Ill revert when Ive studied the Script Engine stuff and got it working. Thanks for the considerable help.

Success, thanks again, forced me up the learning curve a bit further.

@Rusty - When I was learning Script Engine, a GUI was not necessary. The easiest way was to write a short test program in main method then System.out.println.

This is just an example of Java + JavaFX + nashorn Script Engine.
If you want to integrate GraalVM JavaScript, it should be another answer. ( https://github.com/graalvm/polyglot-embedding-demo ) only GraalVM , not include JavaFX.
Remove or Uninstall All

Remove or uninstall JDK , JavaFX, Netbeans...
Remove Environment Variable JAVA_HOME

Install zulu JDK include JavaFX
https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-21-lts&os=windows&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx#zulu
Download -> .msi

zulu21.34.19-ca-fx-jdk21.0.3-win_x64.msi
click zulu21.34.19-ca-fx-jdk21.0.3-win_x64.msi
Drop down Set JAVA_HOME variable , Select Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive

Click Next

Please note that you do not need to set the JAVA_HOME or PATH environment variables yourself.
Because the installation program has been automatically configured.
Check JDK install
Open CMD , input command javac -version
javac 21.0.3

input another command : java -version
openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.34+19-CA (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.34+19-CA (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Install Netbeans 22
Note, please use exe to install and not zip.
click Apache-NetBeans-22-bin-windows-x64.exe

NetBeans will detected Zulu-21
click Next

Click Install
Config JavaFX
Menu Tools -> Options

Click Next

Select accept the terms in all of the license agreements.
Click Install

Click Finish

Click OK
Create JavaFX Example
File -> New Project...


Categories -> Java with Maven
Projects -> FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype

Click Next


Peoject Name: hello1fx
Group Id: com.exmaple

Click Finish

Click Icon (Run)
Then appear the javafx window.
Create Script Engine
Project Directory Tree
hello1fx
├── nbactions.xml
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── com
    │   │   │   └── example
    │   │   │       └── hello1fx
    │   │   │           ├── App.java
    │   │   │           └── PrimaryController.java
    │   │   └── module-info.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── hello1fx
    │                   └── primary.fxml
    └── test
        └── java

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello1fx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
            <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
            <version>15.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.hello1fx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


Add nashorn-core for Script Engine
Change javafx-xxx version from 13 to 21

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
            <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
            <version>15.4</version>
        </dependency>

primary.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.hello1fx.PrimaryController">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="inputArea" text="" promptText="Enter your script here..." />
      <Button fx:id="runButton" text="run" onAction="#execRun"/>
      <Button fx:id="cleanButton" text="clean" onAction="#execClean"/>
      <TextArea fx:id="outputArea" text="" editable="false" />
   </children>
</VBox>

module-info.java

ADD requires java.scripting;
ADD requires jdk.dynalink;

module com.example.hello1fx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    
    requires java.scripting;
    requires jdk.dynalink;
    
    opens com.example.hello1fx to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.hello1fx;
}

App.java
package com.example.hello1fx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Nashorn JavaScript Engine");
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}

PrimaryController.java
package com.example.hello1fx;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class PrimaryController {
    ScriptEngineManager manager ;
    ScriptEngine engine;
    @FXML
    private TextArea inputArea;
    
    @FXML
    private TextArea outputArea;
    
    @FXML
    private void execRun() throws IOException {
            manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
            StringWriter writer  = new StringWriter();
            engine.getContext().setWriter(writer);

            try {
                String inputText = inputArea.getText();
                System.out.println(">>> inputText = "+inputText);
                engine.eval(inputText );
                System.out.println(">>> OK");
                outputArea.setText( "Processed: \n"+writer.toString());
                System.out.println(">>> set output OK");
            } catch (ScriptException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            }       
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void execClean() throws IOException {
        inputArea.clear();
        outputArea.clear();
    }
}

Final Result
Click Icon Run Again

in (1) input area put some java script code.
print('Hello World!')
print(100 + 200)

Click Button run (3)
Then show the result in (2)
You can click Button clean (4) to clean (1) & (2)
